# Christmas cactus oddity

Tags: growth

My Christmas cactus generally has pink flowers. For some reason, it is growing this one single white flower like thing. It’s been on the plant for at least two weeks and has not opened or gotten any bigger. Can anyone tell me what this is. It does not appear to be a flower.[image]

Comment: Please post a photo

Comment: Unfortunately, the photo you posted is out of focus right where the white 'thing' is, so cannot be seen clearly... can you post another in focus version please

Answer (score 1):

Although your photo is very blurry, I think it’s a fruit.

If you are patient and lucky, you may end up with viable seeds in about a year. So it’s ok to just leave the “thing” alone.

Comment: Thank you. I researched "fruit" on Christmas cactus and that is exactly what it is. I've never seen this on any of my other cactus and I've had them for 30 years.